Error buildpacks to deploy Lightning Web Runtime SPA standalone nodeJS project to Heroku
I am trying to deploy my standalone LWR SPA project to Heroku.
I have created a project then connected to the LWR SPA project via command
heroku git:remote -a my-application

Then, I added a buildpack in the project settings which is "nodejs".
I ran git push heroku master, however, there is an error message that
ERROR: Application not supported by 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack
remote:  !

remote:  !     The 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack is set on this application, but was
remote:  !     unable to detect a Node.js codebase.
remote:  !

remote:  !     A Node.js app on Heroku requires a 'package.json' at the root of
remote:  !     the directory structure.
remote:  !

remote:  !     If you are trying to deploy a Node.js application, ensure that this
remote:  !     file is present at the top level directory. This directory has the
remote:  !     following files:
remote:  !

remote:  !     README.md
remote:  !

remote:  !     If you are trying to deploy an application written in another
remote:  !     language, you need to change the list of buildpacks set on your
remote:  !     Heroku app using the 'heroku buildpacks' command.
In the root directory of the LWR SPA project, there is package.json and README.md file.

Since the project is created via command npm init lwr, in the root directory, there are README.md file and package.json file.
The code is running well in local host with command npm run dev, and no matter to make it bundle with npm run build.
My project's drectory structure is like this :
your-lwr-spa-project/
├── README.md
├── __lwr_cache__
├── lwr.config.json
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── .gitignore
├── scripts/
├── site/
└── src/


Your package.json file should specify the Node.js version.
E.g.:
  "engines": {
    "node": "20.x"
  }

This should fix the problem.

Thank you! This is one of the steps I need to do!
